# Clean solution when creating multiple entities from a form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm creating a form in which a user is allowed to create an appointment.
The user has the option to repeat the appointment every week for X amount of times (set using the form).

I could clone the entity in my controller, add a `\DateInterval` for a week and persist it.
However there is some extra logic needed. When a date is already taken, it skips that week. It continues until X amount of appointments have been created.
So far nothing complex.

But I would like to create send a single email with a reminder for all the created appointments.

Again, I could add this to my controller logic, but I need something more robust. The form is used in multiple locations and copying the logic to each controllers seems the wrong solution.

I thought of using `FormEvent`s. However the form data is a single appointment entity and a non-mapped field which holds the number of appointments. The listener won't know the dates for the appointment and thus won't be able to created the email.

The cleanest thing would be a form which returns the appointments so that they can be persisted and send a email containing the dates for these appointments.

Comment: have considered creating a custom service that can be called where need to avoid repeating the logic?

Comment: @Rooneyl Yes I did, but this still need to be called whenever the form is used. This is an OK-solution. But maybe there is a nicer solution without the need to remember to call the service explicitly when the form is valid.

Comment: But that isn't really any different than calling persist with ever form use is it?